# Reading XmlAttribute value

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml that looks like :

```
<OrderID xmlns="http://XMLPolling/JDEOrderQueue">
    <PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue xmlns="" orderno="101" ID="1"/>
</OrderID>
```

I am trying to read the attribute value of orderno. But, my code doesn't work.

```
XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xDoc));
Console.WriteLine(e.XPathSelectElement("orderno").Attribute("ID"));
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "doesn't work"? Aside from anything else, you appear to be looking for an *element* called `orderno`, but you don't have any such elements.

Comment: `orderno` is attribute. You  should select `PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue` element.

Comment: It's also not clear why you're trying to use XPath at all here - if you just need an element, that's easy to do with the `Element` method, once you take the namespace into account. If you can confirm that you just want the ID attribute from the `PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue` element, it's easy to add an answer. But I suspect there are more requirements here.

Comment: I just need the id attribute from PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct implementation:

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://XMLPolling/JDEOrderQueue");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml.xml");
XElement orderID = doc.Elements(ns + "OrderID").FirstOrDefault();
if(orderID != null)
{
    XElement phWork = orderID.Elements("PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue").FirstOrDefault();
    if(phWork != null)
    {
        string oderno = phWork.Attribute("orderno")?.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to query the wrong element. Try:

```
XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(xDoc));
Console.WriteLine(e.XPathSelectElement("PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue").Attribute("ordeno"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your xpath statement. I am thinking it should be something like:

```
e.XPathSelectElement("PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue[@orderno]")
```

Or maybe just

```
e.XPathSelectElement("PHWork.dbo.JDE_Order_Queue")
```